# What does this JQuery instruction do $(function(){...})

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I have been studying JQuery lately and, even though I know some stuff, there's this line in a book that I simply can't figure out:

```
$(
   function()
   {
      current_entry = -1;
   }
);
```

Does anyone know HOW this line works and WHAT it does?

Is it something like a function as selector within the JQuery function?

As a reference that line is used in the book Web Development Recipes, Chapter 2, Recipe 9 - Interacting with Web Pages Using Keyboard Shortcuts (Pg 62).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

It is short form of [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event. It is executed when DOM is ready.

All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:

- $( document ).ready( handler )
- $().ready( handler ) (this is not recommended)
- $( handler )

> The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the
>   DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other
>   event handlers and run other jQuery code. When using scripts that rely
>   on the value of CSS style properties, it's important to reference
>   external stylesheets or embed style elements before referencing the
>   scripts, [jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).